# Why does this git commit exist in the log but not in the log of the file?

Tags: git

How can I investigate how this commit got dropped?

The following commands show no history of the commit in the log:

- `git log -p apps/grants/views.py`
- `gitk apps/grants/views.py`

But the following all show the commit in the log:

- `git log`
- `git log --follow -p apps/grants/views.py`
- `git show 5034d44861fcc39fc28b069501577c8d15321b4f`

UPDATE: No files were renamed in the commit. Here's the output of `git log --stat`:

```
 apps/articles/views.py                    |    4 +-
 apps/grants/tests.py                      |   16 +++++++-----
 apps/grants/views.py                      |   20 +++++++++------
 static/css/modules.css                    |   36 ++++++++++++++--------------
 templates/articles/learning_landing.html  |    2 +-
 templates/grants/fellow_detail.html       |   10 ++++++++
 templates/modules/fellow_search_form.html |    2 +-
 7 files changed, 53 insertions(+), 37 deletions(-)
```

Comment: I've no idea but it looks like the commit never touched the path `apps/grants/views.py` but touched a path that was moved or copied to this path.

Comment: Does `git log --name-status --follow apps/grants/views.py` show you anything informative? (Perhaps the file was renamed to something else, then renamed back.) And also, your FYI is a bit misguided. The commit *hasn't* disappeared; as you can see from a full listing (`git log`), it's there in your history. It wasn't dropped, you're just somehow managing to view history in a way that hides it. Reapplying it would only have an effect if you've subsequently reverted changes made in that commit.

Comment: I'm aware git commits are immutable, so yeah vanish was the wrong word. I could have been more precise in my wording.

Comment: What about the command I suggested you run? Does anything weird happen to the file between the commit in question and HEAD? (And it's not the fact that commits are immutable, but rather the fact that the commit is still an ancestor of your currently checked out commit. It *is* possible to rewrite a branch to point somewhere not including that commit!)

Comment: I think I found the offending commit: `5eaa666`. It's a merge commit with my commit as one of it's parents. When I ran your command all changes were modifies and that commit is not in that log output. Also `git show 5eaa666` of that commit is empty, but `git diff 5034d44..5eaa666` shows that the code was deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that someone's merge commit was the culprit. Any information that wasn't
included was lost in that merge. And since the merge commit didn't add or delete anything it didn't show up in the log run on the file.

The give away was `git show 5eaa666` only had a subset of my changes.

I added the commit back in by cherry picking: `git cherry-pick 5034d44`

Comment: Any idea what flow was it exactly that resulted in this situation? I am also having the same problem exactly. Wanted to figure out what went wrong in the merge commit.

Comment: It appears it was sloppy merging by another developer.

Answer (score 12):

Usually happens with a bad merge (i.e merge conflict)

in order to locate it

`git log -U -m --simplify-merges --merges -- filename`

You will see the missing code as well as the commit ids

Comment: Thanks! This helped me locate the merge commit that caused an issue like this in a similar situation

Answer (score 1):

What happened since the commit? Does that file exist currently or did it exist historically?

If it's been renamed since, then you can only "find" it easily via `git log` with the `--follow` parameter, as you've seen.

Comment: No files were renamed in the commit. I'll add the output of `git log --stat` to the question.

Comment: This answer could be clearer - it's not the target commit that matters, but the history between it and where `git log` is starting from. Something was renamed/copied to apps/grants/views.py *after* the commit in question; being able to walk back to that commit anyway is the entire point of the `--follow` option.

Comment: Yes, definitely - sorry for the confusing response/question, I've reworded it somewhat which hopefully is more accurate.